# how can i change background-color of the body to a linear gradient color

Tags: javascript, css

i have wrote a code that changes background-color of the body element to a random linear-gradient combination of three colors, it's working but i think it's not a professional way to do this, since it's append a style element to the html hierarchy every time button is pressed..

the code of JS is :

````
const foo = new Array(255);
const sheet = document.styleSheets;
const hText = document.getElementsByClassName('.heading__el');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const color = document.querySelector('.color');

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    let tiltDeg = 0;
    let turningAngle1 = 0;
    let turningAngle2 = 35;
    let turningAngle3 = 100;
    let opacity = 1;
    let sheet = document.createElement('style');
    sheet.innerHTML = `body { background: linear-gradient(${tiltDeg}deg, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle1}%, 
    rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle2}%, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle3}%) !important}`;
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);

    color.textContent = (`(${tiltDeg}deg, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle1}%, 
    rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle2}%, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle3}%)`)

    color.style.fontSize = "0.5em";
});```





function getRandomNumber() { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * foo.length);
}
````

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the document's body element, then change its styling like so:

```
document.body.style.background = `linear-gradient(${tiltDeg}deg, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle1}%, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle2}%, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle3}%)`;
```

Comment: i wrote it this way but i think it's wrong since im using ` not '

``` document.body.style.background = `${tiltDeg}deg, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle1}%, 
    rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle2}%, rgba(${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${getRandomNumber()}, ${opacity}) ${turningAngle3}%)`;

Comment: @IbrahimBanat Please see edit, answer should be clearer now

Comment: it's still not changing anything, i tried also to change by manipulating css file and it didn't work, the only way that it did was the one that i wrote above in the question